# (glua) How to check if not var in table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

in my case,

```
self.targets = {}
for k,v in pairs(ents.findInSphere(self:GetPos()) do
-- here, how to check if not v in self.targets?
table.insert(self.targets,v)
```

I tried this

```
for o, p in pairs(self.targets) do
if v ~= p then
```

another

```
if not self.targets[v]
```

can someone help me?

I hope to check if not v in self.targets

but I can't use this

```
for o, p in pairs(self.targets) do
if v == p then continue end
```

because continue not support
and goto not support too

Comment: Are you using `k` from first loop?

Answer (score 0):

Checking `if v ~= p` or `if not self.targets[v]` will fail if `ents.findInSphere()` returns set of newly constructed coordinates.

You see, when you compare two objects with `==` or `~=`, you're not comparing its content, you only check if that's exactly the same instance of an object. It's more like comparing pointers in C/C++.
If coordinate objects you receive from `.findInSphere()` doesn't implement `eq` metamethod, you'll have to compare coordinates yourself. Depending on coordinate implementation, it might look something like:

```
if v[1] == p[1] and v[2] == p[2] then -- ...
-- or
if v.x == p.x and v.y == p.y then -- ...
-- or
if v.equals(p) then -- ..
```

Exact code needed to compare two coordinate objects depends on that coordinate's implementation.

Noticed 'glua' tag. If that's garry's mod, then `ents.FindInSphere()` returns entities, not coordinates. Checking `if not self.targets[v]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're trying to append all new found targets to `self.targets`.

So, we can do this with a construct like...

```lua
self.targets = {}
for k,v in pairs(ents.findInSphere(self:GetPos())) do
    if not table.HasValue(self.targets, v) then
        self.targets[#self.targets+1] = v
    end
end
```

Glua defaultly has `table.HasValue` built in, see [The Docs](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/table/HasValue).
in this case, we just want the logical not of this.